# Saving and loading cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a problem that I can not deal with.
The matter is that program does not save/load cookie properly.

JS code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/MrHishprung/8k61zaf5/

What functions do:
add_condiction - if conds is less than 5 it adds some piece of code, if more than 5 it gives alert.

rem_condiction - if conds is more than 1 it removes some piece of code, if less than 1 it gives alert.

BakeCookie - creates cookie.

Load_Cookie - Gets cookie.

where_is_where - using loaded cookie restores values and HTML code from previous session. (this is not improtant, i want to work with it alone, but to do it i need working cookie code)

How it should behavior:

It should save a cookie something like this:

```
"conds=1; (today's date + 1 year)"
```

When site is reloaded it should take this cookie and split it by ";" and the number should be placed in "CookOut" variable.

```
So if 'conds = 1' it should give me in array:
[0] = 'conds'
[1] = '1' <- this is saved in CookOut
```

What it gives me:

Empty array without saved cookie.